# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime 01:01:0001 error

Tags: c#, datetime

I have string as follow:

```
var StringDate = "Mon Oct 02 2017 16:44:23 GMT 0200 (Central European Summer Time)"
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(StringDate);
```

When I convert this string to date I have error: "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime Exception." and dt = "01:01:0001 00:00:00"

Comment: Have you tried using `ParseExact()`?

Comment: I've tried ParseExact(StringDate, "dd:mm:yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) but it doesn't work

Comment: You need to specify the *exact* format of your *input* string.

Comment: Ask yourself, does `Mon Oct 02 2017 16:44:23 GMT 0200 (Central European Summer Time)` match **exactly** to `dd:mm:yyyy`?

Answer (score 2):

That's not a valid Date/Time format that c# automatically recognizes.

Use this format instead:

```
var StringDate = "Mon Oct 02 2017 16:44:23 +0200";
DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(StringDate);
```

You'll need to modify your incoming string. Use regex for that (take out the parenthesis section, remove the "GMT", and add a plus before the time offset).

The other option is to use `DateTime.ParseExact()`, however you still need to modify your incoming string:

```
var input = "Mon Oct 02 2017 16:44:23 GMT +0200 (Central European Summer Time)";
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(
    input, 
    "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT' zz'00' '(Central European Summer Time)'", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

C# expects any timezone info to have a `-` or `+` before the number, so there is no way to extract the time zone information without adding in that character. Simply "assuming" it is a positive value is not enough.

Also, there is no wildcards for exact format matching, meaning that `(Central European Summer Time)` will be hard-coded in your match string. You're going to run into a lot of problems if you have multiple different time zones - or even if the name of the time zone changes (such as when Daylight Savings time toggles).